# "Polar" vs "Thriller": exact synonyms in French?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes

In a recent "Gallimard présente" email the words "**polar**" and "**thriller**" are used in close proximity but seem to be interchangeable in French. The text:
"Les amateurs de polars plongeront avec délice dans le nouveau Jo Nesbø : un thriller familial glaçant ou dans le premier roman de Chang Kuo-Li : un "thriller politique épicé à souhait".
Is there a difference in the "feel" of these two apparent synonyms?

Comment: Not 100% the same. Polar is a detective story or police procedural, which is a set term in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is they are not interchangeable.

***Polar*** means *roman policier* (detective novel) so is about the subject while ***thriller*** is more about the effect to the reader, as *glaçant* shows (chilling).

Some ***thrillers*** might not be ***polars*** but just ***histoires de zombies***, like Michael Jackson's song who popularized this word in France (and around the world).

See also [this site](https://noircommepolar.com/quelles-differences-entre-le-polar-et-le-thriller/) that tells the differences. Thanks @None.

Comment: Pour étayer https://noircommepolar.com/quelles-differences-entre-le-polar-et-le-thriller/. Perso je suis d'accord avec l'analyse de ce site spécialisé.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and for the reference to the "Noir Comme Polar" site. This nails the difference perfectly!